# GridViewColumn readonly when edited

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have a gridview with some data and for every row there is the possibility to edit the data, so they see the EditTemplateField instead of the templateField.
Now users with a certain position shouldn't be able to edit the column TaskName.

I first tried it like this:

```
protected void gvSubtasks_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView gv = sender as GridView;
            gvSubtasks.Columns[0].ReadOnly= true;
            gv.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
            BindGridView();
        }
```

But it doesn't find a property ReadOnly.

Afterwards I tried it like this:

```
   protected void gvSubtasks_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView gv = sender as GridView;
        gv.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        BindGridView();
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gvSubtasks.Rows)
        {
            TextBox txtTaskName = row.Cells[0].FindControl("txtTaskName") as TextBox;

            if (IsRightUserPosition()){
                txtTaskName.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                txtTaskName.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't find the textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set Readonly property to true :

```
((BoundField)gridView1.Columns[columnIndex]).ReadOnly = true;
```

You can try doing it at RowDataBound event of gridView1

Try using label in edit template.

**C#:**

```
protected bool ShowButton(object DataItem)
{
    //Here you can place as many conditions as you like 
    //Provided you always return either true or false
    if (Put Access condition here)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

**HTML Code :**

```html
 <Columns>
   <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="lbldate" runat="server" Visible='<%# ShowButton(Eval("Process")) %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="lbldate" Visible='<%# ShowButton(Eval("Process")) %>' runat="server" ></asp:Label>
      <asp:TextBox ID="lbldate" Visible='<%# ShowButton(Eval("Process")) %>' runat="server" ></asp:Label>
    </EditItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>    
 </Columns>
```

Comment: My problem is, when I cast it to BoundField, it throws a exception because TemplateField can't be casted to BoundField and TemplateField doesn't have the property ReadOnly

Comment: Try using `row.FindControl("txtTaskName") ` in case#2.Instead of row.Cells[0]

Comment: There I have the same problem

Comment: Did you try using it in rowdatabound event?

Comment: Yes, I now tried if (gvSubtasks.EditIndex >= 0)
                    (gvSubtasks.Rows[gvSubtasks.EditIndex].Cells[0].Controls[1] as TextBox).ReadOnly = true; it sets the value now to true, but I still can change the value

Comment: But users with the right user position should have the possibility to edit the text and when I use a label, they can't do it anymore

Comment: Glad I could help :)